# UK excluded Postcode regex failing

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to do excluded UK postcode validator [it works fine in Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dZ1vT6/74). But fails in browser all results are false with both versions.

```
var testArray = ["AB01 1AA",
"DD02 2RE",
"DG02 2RE",
"EH02 2RE",
"FK02 2RE",
"G02 2RE",
"HS02 2RE",
"IV02 2RE",
"KA02 2RE",
"KW02 2RE",
"KY02 2RE",
"ML02 2RE",
"PA02 2RE",
"PH02 2RE",
"TD02 2RE",
"ZE02 2RE",
"BT02 2RE",
"GY02 2RE",
"JE02 2RE",
"IM02 2RE",
"im11 2RE",
"im21 2ee",
"ZE022RE",
"BT022RE",
"GY022RE",
"je022re"];
var x = /(AB|DD|DG|EH|FK|G|HS|IV|KA|KW|KY|ML|PA|PH|TD|ZE|BT|GY|JE|IM)[0-9]{2}[ ]?[0-9]([a-zA-Z]{2})/;
var reg = RegExp('(AB|DD|DG|EH|FK|G|HS|IV|KA|KW|KY|ML|PA|PH|TD|ZE|BT|GY|JE|IM)[0-9]{2}[ ]?[0-9]([a-zA-Z]{2})','i');

for(var xx in testArray){ console.log(xx+' '+ reg.test(xx)+' '+x.test(xx));}
```

[Also jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/1r7nqd86/)

I must be missing something obvious here.

Comment: I believe your `for` loop iterates over the array's indices, not values.

Comment: `for(var xx in testArray){ var s=testArray[xx]; console.log(s+' '+ reg.test(s)+' '+x.test(s));}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `for..in` for arrays

```
for (var i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++) {
    console.log(testArray[i] +' '+ reg.test(testArray[i])+' '+ x.test(testArray[i]));
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/1r7nqd86/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Look at the output you are getting:

```
0 false false
```

`xx` is always a number. You are testing the array index instead of the values in the array.

```
for(var xx in testArray){ 
    console.log(testArray[xx]+' '+ reg.test(testArray[xx])+' '+x.test(testArray[xx]));
}
```

Comment: One of those cases when I look, but I don't see :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`for (i in array)` iterates over keys of an associative array. You can do:

```
for(var key in testArray) {
   var value = testArray[key]; // get array value
   console.log(value + ' '+ reg.test( value )+' '+x.test( value ));
}
```